# Eliminate space between two bootstrap columns

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I started creating a blog like react application and using bootstrap grid system.
There seems to be a big space between my two columns. Is there a way to get rid of this?
A screen shot is attached.

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
        import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
        import faker from 'faker';

        //Now create a new component

        const App = () => {
            const myCustomStyle = {color:'green', fontSize:'50px'}
            return (
                <div className="container">
                   <div className="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <a href="/" className="avatar"><img alt="avatar" src={faker.image.avatar()}></img></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9" >
                            <p><b>Alex</b><span>Today at 5.00pm</span></p>
                            <p>Great blog post!</p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            )
        }

        ReactDom.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap 4 auto layout columns instead...

`col-auto` - flex shrink
`col` - flex grow

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <a href="/" class="avatar"><img alt="avatar" src="//placehold.it/100" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p><b>Alex</b><span>Today at 5.00pm</span></p>
            <p>Great blog post!</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ZHoBi8rAHB

Comment: I was wondering what is the difference between the two.  Will col-auto always shrink  the column?  If i also want to put a space after  Alex, how can i do that?

Comment: @user2320476 for the space after "Alex", you may use either a JSX space `{' '}` or a simple HTML `&nbsp;`.